# How to compile code written in Solaris using g++?

Tags: c++, porting

I am trying to compile code written by a researcher, the code seems to have been written for solaris machine and compiler, with header files like sunmath.h etc. How do I compile and run this code on my Ubuntu machine running g++?

Source code : http://www.nada.kth.se/~hesj02/

Comment: I think you can't. [Here was a similar thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1998581?start=0&tstart=0), to sum up — those header files weren't ported anywhere from Solaris due to no demand in them. You can only either install Solaris into a virtual machine, e.g. virtualbox, or remove Solaris specific headers from sources, and replace every function that compiler would complain about, with its analogous.